# Is destructor called on reassignment of a mutable variable?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have defined a mutable variable that may be some complex structure containing vectors or other dynamically allocated data with the `Drop` trait. On reassigning that variable, is the destructor called immediately after reassignment?

```rust
let mut x = some_complex_struct;
while some_condition {
    // ...
    x = new_complex_struct;
    // ...
}
```

My interpretation is `x` gains ownership on `new_complex_struct`, its previously owned value becomes unowned, so its destructor would be called right after reassignment. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: [Yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=654b4078914788ea7c98d69c4ff4743d).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My interpretation is `x` gains ownership on `new_complex_struct`, its previously owned value becomes unowned, so its destructor would be called right after reassignment. Is my interpretation correct?

Yes. [This can easily be checked:](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1c00cc757c99397ba11d339a1a830a5)

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo::drop");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo;

    for i in 0..5 {
        println!("Before {}", i);
        f = Foo;
        println!("After {}", i);
    }
}
```

Will as expected print:

```
Before 0
Foo::drop
After 0
Before 1
Foo::drop
After 1
Before 2
Foo::drop
After 2
Before 3
Foo::drop
After 3
Before 4
Foo::drop
After 4
Foo::drop
```

Destructors in Rust are deterministic, so this behaviour is set in stone.