# Rust mutable variable and String

Tags: rust, heap-memory

I have the following piece of code

```
{
    let mut a = String::from("Foo");
    a = String::from("Bar");
}
```

I'm wondering when will the first String be freed is it when I assign a to a different String ? or is it when the scope ends ?

Comment: Answered here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308961/is-destructor-called-on-reassignment-of-a-mutable-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily test this:

```rust
struct B(&'static str);

impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{} B dropped", self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let mut b = B("first");
        println!("{} B created", b.0);
        b = B("second");
        println!("{} B reasigned", b.0);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
first B created
first B dropped
second B reasigned
second B dropped
```

So the first instance of `B` is dropped when the variable is re-assigned. The second one is dopped at the end of the function.

[Playground link to try it yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92b6d02c40aada5e854529724a4b6881)